# Junit - Compare that two XML documents are identical

Tags: java, junit, xunit

I have two XML files and I am comparing them using XUnit using the following test:

```
@Test
public void testSortXML() throws IOException
{
    field = "userid";
    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    xmlStreamSorter.sort(inputStream, outputStream, comparator);
    ByteArrayInputStream expected = new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <users><user><userid>10</userid></user><user><userid>3</userid></user><user><userid>1</userid></user></users>"
            .getBytes());

    System.out.println(outputStream);
    Assert.assertThat(expected, CompareMatcher.isIdenticalTo(outputStream));

}
```

But the test fails with the following error:

```
Expected child nodelist length '3' but was '0' - comparing <users...> at /users[1] to <byteArrayOutputStream...> at /byteArrayOutputStream[1] (DIFFERENT)
```

This is the content of the output variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
  <user>
    <userid>10</userid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <userid>3</userid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <userid>1</userid>
  </user>
</users>
```

They are identical. How come the test fails?

Comment: Just to be sure: you checked that the "expected" thing; when written into a file for example ... really matches the content after "sorting" that other file?

Comment: @GhostCat I've copied and pasted the content of outputStream into the exptected bytearray.

Comment: @RO_engineer I've also did this   Assert.assertThat(expected.toString(), CoreMatchers.equalTo(outputStream.toString()));  

but I got the same result

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I did not ignored the whitespace. 
To do it with XUnit 2.x just create a custom Diff this way:

```
Diff xmlDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(expected)
    .withTest(outputStream.toString())
    .ignoreComments()
    .ignoreWhitespace()
    .build();
```

And then you can do this:

```
Assert.assertFalse(
    "The resulting XML is not correctly sorted",
    xmlDiff.hasDifferences()
);
```

Comment: The question talks about JUnit, but this answer is about XUnit. Can someone fix this mismatch please?

Comment: When you wrote XUnit, did you maybe mean XMLUnit?